# Can anyone identify board game with 2 rows 2 holes wide each and 2 upright metal pins?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image: Game board with Gatorade bottle next to it for scale]
The Gatorade bottle has been placed for scale

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cribbage

Comment: Cracker Barrel appetizer

Answer (score 24):

This is a basic [cribbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cribbage) board.

The pegs are moved alternatively to track score for each of two players. There are sixty holes so that each player completes a number of "laps of the board" to reach a winning score of 61 or 121.

Comment: Probably should add that this is a SCORE board - not the actual game itself (which is a card game)

Comment: ?? I'm not sure how else you can interpret "to track score" especially if you've read that it's for cribbage and have made some effort to work out what that game is.

Comment: The winning score is 61 or 121. You must exit the track to win.